# curl only works on some servers

Tags: php, linux, curl, centos

I have two almost identical Centos Linux servers.  One is physical located in my home, runs iptables, and has a hardware firewall (Asus wireless router) between it and the Internet.  The other is a remote VPS, runs iptables, and as far as I know doesn't have a hardware firewall.  Neither use selinux (yes, I know I should use it).

The following script works as desired on the VPS, but provides no response on the physical machine.

What might cause this, and how can it be fixed?

```
<?php
$source='http://www.google.com/uds/Gfeeds?context=0&num=10&hl=en&output=json&refreshInterval=0&q=http%3A%2F%2Fconstruction.com%2Frss%2Fconstruction.xml%3F1414243577&v=1.0&nocache=0';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo($data);
?>
```

Comment: Can you curl that URL from the shell ? You can place `echo curl_error($ch);` just before closing the handle to check for any errors.

Comment: @Himal.  Haven't yet tried curl from the shell, but your other suggestion definitely is on to something: `Couldn't resolve host 'www.google.com'`.  I've been thinking it was some sort of firewall issue, but it isn't.  Thoughts were to go next?  Thanks

Comment: [This](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables) might help.You can use `iptables -L` to list the rules.did you modify it ? you can try [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13755) to reset it back to default.I would try to find out what's actually blocking the DNS request first.iptable or the hardware firewall.

Comment: @Himal.  I think it is the lack of nameservers.  I edit `/etc/resolv.conf` to add 8.8.8.8, but whenever I reboot the server, it goes back to `generated by /sbin/dhclient-script.... nameserver 192.168.1.1`.

Comment: Turns out my nameserver kept going away in resolv.conf.  Added PEERDNS=no to my /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-xxx files, and all is good.  Thanks for the help.